# Определить xpath locator элемента на странице

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[image: field]

Мне нужно проверить/убедиться, что текст "(`carrier specific`)" существует и лежит в нужном месте.

Я делаю

```
try: self.assertEqual("(carrier specific)", sel.get_table("//form/fieldset[4]/table.2.1"))
```

но он никак не хочет "подцепить" этот текст (обращается к пустому полю `National prefix`, но не к тексту сразу за ним). Мне нужно как-то определить локейшн этого текста на страничке, т.е. обратиться к этому элементу через xpath/css.

```
<fieldset class="group">
<fieldset class="group">
<fieldset class="group">
<fieldset class="group">
<legend>Dialing Location</legend>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr title="The country code.">
<tr title="The area code.">
<tr title="The national trunk prefix.">
<td>National Prefix</td>
<td>
<input maxlength="256" size="10" value="" name="dl-ntp">
(carrier specific)
</td>
</tr>
```

[image: code]

Comment: Интересно, а используете `python`? А так, вам наверное поможет `next-sibling` или как то так. И лучше к вопросу добавьте ту таблицу как текст (картинку можно и оставить)

Comment: В вопрос, пожалуйста. Кнопка `править`

Answer (score 3):

xpath для получения текста из описанной вами ноды: `//input[@name='dl-ntp']/../text()[boolean(string-length(normalize-space(.)))]`

xpath для проверки совпадения ожидаемого текста в описанной ноде: `//input[@name='dl-ntp']/ancestor::*[1][contains(.,'carrier specific')]`

Если используете python, то может пригодиться:
`driver.execute_script("return document.evaluate('//input[@name='dl-ntp']/../text()[boolean(string-length(normalize-space(.)))]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().data")`